# On notification centre, when I receive a notification and click on it, it doesn’t open straight away

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

Can anyone tell me how to turn this feature off? When I click on a notification it then shows me that open button, which I then have to click to go onto the app. I want to be able to just click the notification and go directly to the app but cant figure out how to change this?
This is on IOS13 
[image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/370613/edit) it to include the version of iOS you're running?

Comment: Hi yeah I’m using IOS 13, I’m wondering whether it’s a bug or something? Because I can’t find any way to change it